# how to get the camera pose in RGBDSLAM use a Raptor-E

Tags: slam, navigation, kinect

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello . now i can run rgbdslam . the rgbdslam can get 6-DOF . but the pose of kinect include "tx ty tz qx qy qz qw", that contain 7 numbers . what's meaning about that ?(I have understood the meaning)   in the future, i have a pose capture system[link text](http://www.motionanalysis.com/html/industrial/raptore.html) ,how can i get the real pose of kinect . thanks a lot .

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/66294/how-to-get-the-camera-pose-in-rgbdslam--use-a----raptor-e/) by [longzhixi123](https://answers.ros.org/users/3030/longzhixi123/) on ROS Answers with karma: 78 on 2013-06-30

Post score: -2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lindzey](https://answers.ros.org/users/2444/lindzey/) on 2013-07-07**:
I downvoted this question for a number of reasons: it isn't clearly written, has multiple questions rolled into one, and doesn't contain enough details about your problems.

**Comment by [lindzey](https://answers.ros.org/users/2444/lindzey/) on 2013-07-07**:
ROSanswers is a MUCH friendlier place than the forums that these guides on asking questions were written for, but they may help. [1] http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx [2] http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To answer one of your questions: you need to learn about quaternions, which are how rotations are represented within ROS.

[These](http://answers.ros.org/question/9981/what-are-quaternions-and-how-can-i-use-them/) [questions](http://answers.ros.org/question/9772/quaternions-orientation-representation/), especially the links in the answers, are probably a good start.

---

Originally posted by [lindzey](https://answers.ros.org/users/2444/lindzey/) with karma: 1780 on 2013-07-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1